# rewrite block not working again

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, overrides

hello I have a problem again with my rewrite, I tried to rewrite the product view block

**app/code/local/Lesson/Test/etc/config.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Lesson_Test>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </Lesson_Test>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <blocks>
                <catalog>
                    <rewrite>
                        <product_view>Lesson_Test_Block_Catalog_Product_View</product_view>
                    </rewrite>
                </catalog>
            </blocks>
        </global>
    </config>
```

**app/code/local/Lesson/Test/Block/Catalog/Product/View.php**

```
<?php
Class Lesson_Test_Block_Catalog_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
{
    public function afficherLesInfos()
    {
        return 'les infos complementaires';
    }
}
```

**app/etc/modules/Lesson.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lesson_Test>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Lesson_Test>
    </modules>
</config>
```

I tried to access

```
http://127.0.0.1/magento/magento-tutorial/index.php/
http://127.0.0.1/magento/magento-tutorial/index.php/lesson
http://127.0.0.1/magento/magento-tutorial/index.php/lesson/product
http://127.0.0.1/magento/magento-tutorial/index.php/lesson/product/view
http://127.0.0.1/magento/magento-tutorial/index.php/product/view
http://127.0.0.1/magento/magento-tutorial/index.php/lesson/catalog/product/view
```

no one of that at work

Comment: your global configuration file name should  be `Lesson_Test.xml` instead of `Lesson.xml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm confused by what you want to achieve here.

**Rewriting a block does not involve changing the URLs.**

In your case, you're rewriting the catalog product view block so you just need to **access a normal product view page**.

But the way you're rewriting the block and adding a new method `afficherLesInfos` **won't do anything if you don't call that method in your template**.

To get that working you need to edit `app/design/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` and add the following line to the template:

```
<?php echo $this->afficherLesInfos(); ?>
```

Also `app/code/local/Lesson/Test/etc/config.php` must be an XML file and not a PHP file like you said.

On top of that, as Amit said, your global config should be renamed from `Lesson.xml` to `Lesson_Test.xml`

Comment: thanks @Raphael but it still not work (404 not found), i've create a template, layout, and i add on config and i acces http://127.0.0.1/magento/magento-tutorial/index.php/lesson

Comment: @gufran I don't understand why you're trying to access 127.0.0.1/magento/magento-tutorial/index.php/lesson ? Your code only implies block rewrite and does not declare custom route. You should try to access a product page as I said in my answer

Comment: sorry @Raphael, thanks i understand know :)
i tried access this page (my some product) http://127.0.0.1/magento/magento-tutorial/index.php/product-coba.html
you are my hero :)